# Material for printing flowerpots

Tags: material, food

I want to print a flowerpots, for advanced watering system.

Plants are going to be eaten.

What is the most suitable material, when we consider the fact, that we do not want to just make forms and do clay flowerpots(which may seem most healthier), but having them directly printed.

What are the temperatures that makes plastics emit dangerous components in surrounding water, and what are those components?

Is there some "totally safe" material out there? I was thinking of PLA or PETG, because I've already heard that ABS is not safe for edibles.

Comment: I'd say PLA is a good choice.

Comment: Note the threads mentioning that PLA becomes brittle with moisture.  So, if you use PLA, you will need to consider the pot loosing flexibility.  Thus, it needs to be thick enough not to flex.

Comment: Every answer has it's benefits, is there way how to make two answers checked?

Comment: From https://www.3dhubs.com/knowledge-base/pla-vs-abs-whats-difference

PLA is stable in general atmospheric conditions and will biodegrade within 50 days in industrial composters and 48 months in water. ABS is not biodegradable, however it is recyclable. PLA is regularly used for the production of food related items, however confirmation by the filament manufacturer that it is safe to do so is recommended.

Comment: ASA is better if exposed to sunlight, but not easy to use. https://www.simplify3d.com/support/materials-guide/asa/

Answer (score 3):

I printed some pots for sprouting seedlings this year from PLA.  A square array of pots with tiny drainage holes in the bottom.

The array filled the bed of a Prusa3d i3m3.

The seeds sprouted, except for the ground cherries, which I think failed because the seeds were bad.

I had good germination rates for tomatoes and basil.

According to the FDA, ABS is generally safe for food, although like any filament the pigment and any added chemicals may be contraindicated for continued health.

Comment: What colour is "without pigment"?

Comment: Most filaments are available in natural.  They are typically translucent, some tend to be slightly yellow.

Answer (score 3):

Given the tendancy for extrusion 3D prints to be porous, aside from any potential health/ingestion issues, I'd recommend lining your pots after printing. You could use an epoxy that's food-rated, or a thin layer of concrete, or even sheet metal if you have access to a bender (or aluminum foil, for that matter).

So far as temperature-dependent outgassing, that's not an issue unless your garden will reach temperatures over 150 Celsius :-)